# DRF - serialize different models into one

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have several models that have a user as a foreign key. For example, I have model `Profile`, model `profilePic` and model `userQuestions` - in all that models user is foreign key.

Is the there a way a can get a `profile`, a `profilePic` and `userQuestions` that corresponds to given user in one single json response ?

my models.py is following

```
class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   gender = models.CharField(max_length=2)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   birthday = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
   weight = models.IntegerField(default=0)
   heigth = models.IntegerField(default=0)
   sign = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=SIGNS_CHOICES, default='E')
   orientation = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=ORIENTATION_CHOICES, default='E')
   bodytype = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=BODYTYPE_CHOICES, default='E')
   education = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=EDUCATION_CHOICES, default='E')
   religion = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=RELIGION_CHOICES, default='E')
   smoking = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=SMOKING_CHOICES, default='E')
   alcohol = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=ALCOHOL_CHOICES, default='E')
   kids = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=KIDS_CHOICES, default='E')
   pets = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=KIDS_CHOICES, default='E')
   location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   latitude = models.FloatField()
   longtitude = models.FloatField()

class ProfileFields(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   text = models.TextField()
   order = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class ProfilePic(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   profilePic = models.ImageField(upload_to='Images/', default='Images/None/No-img.jpg')

class Pics(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='Images/', default='Images/None/No-img.jpg')
```

UPD

tried to add

```
def to_representation(self, data):
    profile_info = {kv: data[kv] for kv in data if kv in list(ProfileSerializer.Meta.fields)}
    profile_pic_info = {kv: data[kv] for kv in data if kv in list(ProfilePicSerializer.Meta.fields)}

    return super(DeviceInfoSerializer, self).to_representation({
    'profile': profile_info,
    'profile_pic': profile_pic_info,
    })
```

but now it says object 'User' is not iteratable

Comment: yes, but you have to post your models.py

Comment: @itzmeontv done

Answer (score 1):

You can add them as [nested serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects) to your `UserSerializer`. Something like this.

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'

class ProfilePicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    class Meta:
        model = ProfilePic
        fields = '__all__'

class UserQuestionsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    class Meta:
        model = UserQuestions
        fields = '__all__'

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    profile = ProfileSerializer(many=False)
    profilepic = ProfilePicSerializer(many=False)
    user_questions = UserQuestionsSerializer(mane=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: I get error of "Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `profile_pic` on serializer `UserSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `User` instance.
Original exception text was: "User" object has no attribute "profile_pic"

Comment: @AlexeyK can you add full stack trace of this error?

Answer (score 0):

I *struggled* with the same issue about a month ago and found no good answer on SO. 
Sardorbek's answer is totally correct in case you dont care if json response is flat or not. JSON created by that code is something like:

```
{ 
  "profile": {"name": ..., "gender": ..., "birthday": ...,},
  "profile_pic": {"profilePic": ...., },
  "user_questions": [{...}, {...}, ...]
  User model attributes go here...
}
```

but if you want it to be flat, like:

```
{
    "name": ...,
    "gender": ...,
    "birthday": ...,
    ....
    "profilePic": ...,
    "user_questions": [{...}, {...}, ...],
    User model attributes go here...
}
```

You need a little hack here. Override `to_internal_value` in `UserSerializer` class in this way:

```
def to_internal_value(self, data):
    profile_info = {kv: data[kv] for kv in data if kv in list(ProfileSerializer.Meta.fields)}
    profile_pic_info = {kv: data[kv] for kv in data if kv in list(ProfilePicSerializer.Meta.fields)}

    return super(DeviceInfoSerializer, self).to_internal_value({
        'profile': profile_info,
        'profile_pic': profile_pic_info,
    })
```

You may need to override `to_representation` too, with similar idea.

Comment: tried to add this to serializer, but it return only user model fields that are specified in meta class

Comment: also tried to override to_representation - added upd to question